# refresh listview when using hashmap

Tags: android, android-listview, hashmap

I have a multiline listview , implemented using hashmaps . I get my data from a database .

I have another activity in which i am adding my items , which is being added to the database . Now when pressing the save button , the new added item should appear immediately in the listview which is implemented in a fragment .  I can't figure out how to refresh the listview in this activity .

here's my fragment implementing the listview :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {             
            myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);



            l = db.getAllEntries();

            list = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.entrylist);
            mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


            HashMap<String,String> item;


            while(!l.isEmpty()){

                e = l.get(0);
                l.remove(0);

              item = new HashMap<String,String>();

              item.put( "line1", e._totime + " - " + e._totime);
              item.put( "line2", e._subject);
              item.put( "line3", e._place);
              mylist.add(n++,item);
            }

              sa = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylist,
                        R.layout.multi_line,
                        new String[] { "line1","line2", "line3" },
                        new int[] {R.id.line_a, R.id.line_b, R.id.line_c}); 

            list.setAdapter(sa);
return myView;
    }
```

and here in this activity i am adding items to the database , which should immediately appear in my listview above :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.save:



      sub = subject.getText().toString();
      teach = teacher.getText().toString();
      pla = place.getText().toString();
      da = day.getSelectedItem().toString();
      fro = fromtime.getText().toString();
      to = totime.getText().toString();


      i = new Entries(sub,teach,pla,da,fro,to);
      db.addEntry(i);



      FragmentView1 f = (FragmentView1) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentView1.class.getName());


      l = db.getAllEntries();
      HashMap<String,String> map;


      while(!l.isEmpty()){

        e = l.get(0);
        l.remove(0);

        map = new HashMap<String,String>();

        map.put( "line1", e._fromtime + " - " + e._totime);
        map.put( "line2", e._subject);
        map.put( "line3", e._place);
        f.getArrayList().add(n++,map);    //nullpointerexception here
      }
      f.getMyListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();


        /*Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the " + getResources().getString(R.string.save) + " menu option",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        return true;


  default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because findFragmentByTag() is not able to find the required fragment and so is returning null, resulting in NullPointerException when you try to access it.
You can try a workaround by retrieving the tag for fragment and storing it in activity class variable for further access as follows:

In your activity class, declare a private String variable and getter/setter methods for it:

```
    public String fragmentView1Tag;

public String getfragmentView1Tag() {
    return fragmentView1Tag;
}

public void setfragmentView1Tag(String fragmentView1Tag) {
    this.fragmentView1Tag = fragmentView1Tag;
}
```

In FragmentView1 class, retrieve the tag of the fragment and set fragmentView1Tag variable:

```
    String tag = getTag();
    ((YourActivityName) getActivity()).setfragmentView1Tag(tag);
```

And now while retrieving the fragment in activity class, use the above getter method:

```
    FragmentView1 f = (FragmentView1) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getfragmentView1Tag);
```

Comment: ((YourActivityName) getActivity()).setfragmentView1Tag(tag) is giving me classcastexception , i am actually trying to call fragment in other activity , not to main activity ( parent activity of this fragment)

Comment: You can save the updates to the database from the other activity. And for updating the results in the list (contained in fragment of another activity)you can write the code for update in onResume() callback method of Fragment class instead of trying to call any of its method. So whenever the fragment comes into focus, it will always fetch the update data in the db. For more info: [Fragment Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a cursor to get all the rows from the database. Then use a cursor adapter to populate the list. After you add a new row to the database, just call notifyDataSetChanged(); on the cursor adapter.

Comment: i am able to populate my list from the database , i am just not able to populate immediately after clicking on the save button , i have to reopen my app . i want to refresh my listview with new added item to the database when "save" button is clicked

Comment: are you saying i should use cursor adapter again inside onoptionitemclicked to populate the list

Comment: @user1304 if you use a cursor adapter to populate the list, you only need to call notifydatasetchanged on that adapter to update the list

Comment: @user1304 wait i get your point, i think you could just call notifydatasetchanged on your simple adapter, but you need to update mylist so that it contains the new entry

Comment: @user1304 you can just add the new entry to mylist after you insert it into the database

Comment: check my edit , i did that , but now i am getting a nullpointerexception

Comment: after adding a new entry , i am getting all entries once again from database , and adding them to mylist, but it's giving nullpointerexception , i am missing something there

Comment: check if your f.getmylistadapter returned null pointer, if so, you should get the listview and call getadapter on that listview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23724/discussion-between-ryan-huang-and-user1304)

Comment: nullpointerexception is here : f.getArrayList().add(n++,map);