# Android Listview not refreshing

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-listview

Hi my program should update the listview based on which radiobutton is selected and show all records of the one of the two tables.

As far as I can tell the records are in fact populated, it seems not to be refreshing the listview itself.  Please help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

In onCreate:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
                RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);

                switch(checkedId)
                {
                case R.id.radio0:
                    {
                        rb2.setChecked(false);          
//                      populateList();
//                      ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
//                      lview.invalidateViews();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.radio1:
                {
                        rb1.setChecked(false);
//                      populateList();
//                      ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
//                      lview.invalidateViews();
                }
                    break;
                }
                populateList();  
//              ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
//              lview.updateViewLayout();
            }


        });
```

Methods used:

```
 private void populateList() 
    {
        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        EditText mEdit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
        insertConstant();

        if(rb1.isChecked() == true)
        {
             auditds = new ProjectAuditingDataSource(this);
                auditds.open();

                List<DataCapture> auditValues = auditds.getAllAudits();
                ArrayAdapter<DataCapture> auditadapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataCapture>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, auditValues);

                int countaudits = 0; 
                int auditsize = auditValues.size();

                while (countaudits < auditsize)
                {
                    HashMap temp2 = new HashMap();          

                    temp2.put(FIRST_COLUMN,auditValues.get(countaudits).getId());
                    temp2.put(SECOND_COLUMN,auditValues.get(countaudits).getName());
                    temp2.put(THIRD_COLUMN, auditValues.get(countaudits).getXcoordinate());             
                    temp2.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, auditValues.get(countaudits).getVMstartdate());

                    list.add(temp2);
                    countaudits++;
                }

        }   

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if(rb2.isChecked() == true)
        {
            assetsds = new AssetsDataSource(this);
            assetsds.open();

            List<Assets> assetValues = assetsds.getAllAssets();
            ArrayAdapter<Assets> assetadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Assets>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, assetValues);

            int countassets = 0; 
            int size = assetValues.size();

            while (countassets < size)
            {
                HashMap temp = new HashMap();           

                temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN,assetValues.get(countassets).getAssetId());
                temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN,assetValues.get(countassets).getAssetDescription());
                temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, assetValues.get(countassets).getInspectorId());
                temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN,"insert time here");

                list.add(temp);
                countassets++;
            }
        }
        ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lview.invalidateViews();    
    }

public void insertConstant()
    {
        list.clear();
        HashMap temp0 = new HashMap();    

        temp0.put(FIRST_COLUMN, com.example.demoapplication1.Constant.FIRST_COLUMN);
        temp0.put(SECOND_COLUMN, com.example.demoapplication1.Constant.SECOND_COLUMN);
        temp0.put(THIRD_COLUMN,  com.example.demoapplication1.Constant.THIRD_COLUMN);
        temp0.put(FOURTH_COLUMN,  com.example.demoapplication1.Constant.FOURTH_COLUMN);

        list.add(temp0);
    }
```

Let me know if you require more information

Comment: you have to call notifyDataSetChanged() from your list adaper every time you update your list view.

Answer (score 1):

You missed setting the adapter on the listview :

```
lview.setAdapter(assetadapter);
```

Comment: Hi thanks that seems to be working.  My listview has just gone a little crazy with the formatting but I guess the main problem is fixed.  Thanks

Comment: ok. Please validate my answer (little check mark under vote buttons).

Comment: Unfortunately, I thought it was the right answer but the lview.setAdapter(assetadapter) does NOT FIX the problem because the only time I use the adapters are when I put values in the temp HashMap.  The custom listview then uses hashmap to populate the list not the adapters.  SO THIS QUESTION IS NOT RESOLVED YET, please let me know what you think - how do I resolve this - It will have to be something to do with hashmap to refresh the list (I think it does populate but does not show in listview).

Comment: ok, but you had not told us you use a custom listview ! :) Can you add details about that ? (custom listview, how it is working, hashmap ?)

Comment: yes sorry that's my bad.  A temporary hashmap object is created with 4 fields/columns.  In a loop this objects gets the 4 columns information and adds that to the list ( list.add(temp);)  After all records are added - this is the point where it should show it in the list.  This works fine the first time when its created but not when I want it to refresh.  Also this works fine when I delete on selected record in listview - it immediately refreshes and record is removed.  With (list.remove(id);)

Comment: Ive also looked at this but I don't know how this will work - any thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630197/refresh-listview-when-using-hashmap

Answer (score 0):

set the Adapter to the listview

You need to call the notifyDataSetChanged() of Adapter when you need the listview to be updated

Comment: That doesn't work as I'm not actually working with adapters only using their values